# .NET 6.0 not listed in VS2022 (17.1.3)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

As far as I know VS2022 should support dotnet 6.0 framework and make it easily targetable... But for some reason VS2022 doesn't have framework target option for .NET 6.0 when I try to create WinForm App...

Only available frameworks are:

- .NET framework 2.0
- .NET framework 3.0
- .NET framework 3.5
- .NET framework 4.7.2
- .NET framework 4.8

https://prnt.sc/zP2h6_DL9a5q

I've been looking into this and I only found users have similar problem but their problems solution is based on their Visual Studio version since everyone with similar problem use/used vs2019...

If you have any idea how I can make .NET 6.0 targetable in Frameworks dropdown list I'd be very grateful.

Thanks in advance, Luke.

Comment: Are you sure you have picked the correct template?
Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/get-started/create-app-visual-studio?view=netdesktop-6.0

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I had to create a project in older version of .NET e.g. 4.8, then build solution and upgrade it manually with dotnet tool called upgrade assistant in order to update my project to 6.0

But then another problem showed up with Resources, for some reason I cannot build projects if I import images to Properties\Resources.resx after updating manually to .NET 6.0

I'll post updates because I am trying few different solutions at this time that may help.

Thanks

Comment: You picked the wrong Template: `Windows Forms App (.NET Framework`) instead of `Windows Forms App`. Assuming you have installed all the available Templates in the `.NET Desktop development` workload. Run the VS Installer and verify. It's usually included by default.

Comment: Oh, you are right man. Selecting Windows Forms App template gave me an option for .NET 6.0

My question is what's the difference between WinForm App (.NET Framework) and WinForm App.

However thanks I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between .NET and .NET Framework is that

> Developers use the .NET Framework to create Windows desktop applications and server based applications..NET is used to create applications that could run on Windows, Linux and Mac. It does not support creating Windows desktop applications on platforms other than Windows.

> .NET 5+ (including .NET Core) is the latest implementation and runs on any platform. .NET Framework is the original implementation of .NET, and runs only on Windows.

You can see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/introduction#net-core-net-framework-mono-uwp).

If you want to migrate from .NET Framework to .NET you  can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/).

Comment: Yeah but what is the benefit of using .NET Frameworks instead of .NET if .NET Frameworks could run on other platforms as well. And I thought WinForms are exclusive to windows. But doing research on your answer I found that you are correct. 

Thank you for your input, it really means a lot since I asked this question (What is the difference) to my professor in school and she said that we use .NET Framework because  some methods and god knows what wouldn't work on .NET 6.0.

Comment: And we have a simple task to make winform application that change pictures based on timer ticks so it makes animation. Tbh, childs play compared what I do as a hobby at home. Only thing was that I forgot to enable the timer so it didn't work as intended. Code was fine and she checked it and immediately told me it is because I run on .NET 6.0 which made 0 absolute sense... So to prove she is wrong I did everything on framework she uses and then I realized I forgot to enable the timer... I just hate when they don't know answer to students question so they answer with anything that would make sen